# AWS Lambda not Pulling Data from DynamoDB and returning in on AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

I am trying to pull and display data from DynamoDb by using AWS Lambda function and have it display on AWS Lex.  It is returning the if portion with the word "undefined" in the place where the data should be. The information is in the DynamoDB database.  I am mainly using AWS servers and building this serverless Lex bot application.

AWS code Segments

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};

function getExamSchedule(exam2, table){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        var info = 0;
        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            FilterExpression: "#key = :data",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#key": "Resource",
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{
                ":data": exam2
            }
        };
        db.scan(params, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error: " + err);
                info = 0;
            } else {
                console.log("Success", data);
                
                info = {"ClassID" :data.Items[0].ClassID, "ExamDate " :data.Items[0].ExamDate, 
                        "ExamEndTime:" :data.Items[0].ExamEndTime, "ExamLocation" :data.Items[0].ExamLocation, 
                        "ExamStartTime" :data.Items[0].ExamStartTime};
            }
            resolve(info);
        });
    });
}
```

This is the portion where the issue might be occurring.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var exam2 = event.currentIntent.slots.ClassID;
    var info = await getExamSchedule(exam2, "Final_Exams");
    var res;
    // if (info !== 0)
    if(info != null){
        res =`The exam information for ${exam2} is ${info.ClassID} Date: ${info.ExamDate} 
            End time:  ${info.ExamEndTime} Location: ${info.ExamLocation} Start time: ${info.ExamStartTime}`;
    } else {
        res = `The exam is not entered into our database, please look for another exam.`;
    }
    
    callback(null, {
        "dialogAction": {
            "type":"Close",
            "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
            "message":{
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": res
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How did you solved this issue @BlackSpadeK

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps share some of the logs and/or stack traces that you encounter when running the code?

Comment: This type of request should be a comment under the question.